# Google cloud Rest API to retrieve tenant id

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have api_key for my project on google cloud and I am able to generate authorization code via client_id and subsequently auth token using authorization code.
What is the rest api code to retrieve tenant information ? Can anyone please put a curl command for that.

Comment: What do you mean by `tenant` information? Tenant is an Azure term.

Comment: Do you mean this API ?
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants/list

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation about [how to get tenants list using API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants/list); even more - yoo can test it yourself using the pane on the right.

Another piece of documentation you might be interested in to help you understand [how this particular API works](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.tenants?hl=pl) and what kind of reply you might expect.

More genral explanation of [how to construct API's requests you can find here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses#constructing_an_api_request).